# When to use "from django.contrib.gis.db import models"?

Tags: django, import, model, geodjango

I am working on a django project that uses Postgres with the PostGIS extension enabled.
When creating my models, should I use the following code in all my django apps or only in apps that contain models with geolocation fields?

`from django.contrib.gis.db import models`

Comment: I think it will be better to use in every models. But in general models containing  geolocation fields must extends `gis.db.models` and it is optional for other models.

Comment: So you're saying it's okay to leave the rest of my apps at "from django.db import models"? I don't know how to test if either is alright. I was worried that this one won't work anymore because I had to change the name of the db engine in settings.py to "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis"

Comment: Yah it is ok to leave the rest of my apps at "from django.db import models"